# Unexpected highlight feature in Android Studio

Tags: android-activity, methods, import, highlight

i'm a newbie to Android. I've just taken my first step into this, and i have met this problem. It's not exactly an error, but it makes me feel uncomfortable while coding.
What i'm talking about is a highlight feature in Android Studio, it highlights all the imports, 'MainActivity', variables and methods...
Does anyone know how to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: You'll be able to alter the syntax theme somewhere in your editor, which will fix the problem.

Comment: Actually, i've tried changin some themes, but it seems to be useless

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out, the answer is on General settings of IDE!
Here, u can choose to customize your highlight features!
After all, i wanna say thank to Marty for ur hint!

[image: SS]

Comment: Could you please take a look at my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178321/why-does-android-studio-ide-focuses-highlights-values? Thanks.