# Why does Android Studio IDE focuses/highlights values?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing an issue when moving mouse into editor field, the Android Studio IDE highlights some values in a rectangle:

[image: Screen]

What is that and how can I disable it? It's really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to highlight Live Edit of Compose Literals, i.e. values that can change in your Live Edits. You can disable it by unticking effects in settings. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I uninstalled that AS to fix that becouse couldn't find that option. Good to know for next time